# How does containers scale in an AWS elasticbeanstalk multi-container

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, containers, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I have a 3 containers; One for nginx(proxy and frontend), another container for user system/api and finally last for Blog post.

So when the elasticbean tries to scale does it scale all of these containers at once or it only scales the specific type of container/s which is getting high traffic?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it scales all at once - which makes no sense. Please, I would love to be proved wrong here.

Comment: Exactly my thought. If it is like that then better using single container elasticbean.